# Получение номера устройства аудиозахвата/аудиовоспроизведения, улучшение качества записи голоса

Tags: c#, звукозапись, naudio

В моём проекте используется запись голоса. Соответственно, должно быть реализовано и воспроизведение.

Для упрощения задачи я использую библиотеку NAudio.
Однако, в данном решении для выбора устройства аудиозахвата/аудиовоспроизведения требуется указать его `Device Number` (например, для дефолтного устройства, он всегда имеет значение 0).

Вот так, например, это можно сделать:

```
int waveInDevices = WaveIn.DeviceCount;
for (int waveInDevice = 0; waveInDevice < waveInDevices; waveInDevice++)
{
    WaveInCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveIn.GetCapabilities(waveInDevice);
    Console.WriteLine("Device {0}: {1}, {2} channels", waveInDevice, deviceInfo.ProductName, deviceInfo.Channels);
}
```

Но есть одно нетерпимое ограничение: длина имени устройства не может быть больше 31 символа. Имя мне требуется для того, чтобы отобразить его для пользователя, оно однозначно должно быть полным. Поэтому, мне требуется альтернативное решение получения списка. В таком решении должно быть можно получить `Device Number`.

Странно, но я не могу найти такого параметра в принципе:

```
Availability : 
Caption : Conexant SmartAudio HD
ConfigManagerErrorCode : 0
ConfigManagerUserConfig : False
CreationClassName : Win32_SoundDevice
Description : Conexant SmartAudio HD
DeviceID : HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_14F1&DEV_506E&SUBSYS_17AAA001&REV_1000\4&3A3FC0BE&0&0001
DMABufferSize : 
ErrorCleared : 
ErrorDescription : 
InstallDate : 
LastErrorCode : 
Manufacturer : Conexant
MPU401Address : 
Name : Conexant SmartAudio HD
PNPDeviceID : HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_14F1&DEV_506E&SUBSYS_17AAA001&REV_1000\4&3A3FC0BE&0&0001
PowerManagementCapabilities : 
PowerManagementSupported : False
ProductName : Conexant SmartAudio HD
Status : OK
StatusInfo : 3
SystemCreationClassName : Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName : MYPC
```

Строка запроса, но дело, кажется, далеко не в ней: `SELECT * FROM Win32_SoundDevice`.

---

Так же меня интересуют вопросы улучшения качества записи именно голоса. Например, какую брать частоту записи и ширину сэмпла, требуются ли какие-либо частотные фильтры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему бы не воспользоваться waveInGetDevCaps для получения данных о устройстве? Берем количество через waveInGetNumDevs() и пробегаемся по всем, пока не найдем интересующее. Проще и эффективнее не придумать, никаких ограничений библиотек, полный контроль.

Частоту записи лучше брать ту, которую устройство поддерживает нативно, как правило это 44100 или 48000 герц.

По моим личным наблюдениям, с учетом моей тугоухости, 10 бит на семпл более чем достаточно, поэтому если речь не идет о каком-то эмбеддеде, то лучше брать 16 бит на семпл, как сделано в подавляющем количестве программ. Однако осторожно, если целевая аудитория хипстеры, то без поддержки 8-байтовых даблов вас просто заклюют и софтину нарекут говнософтом.

При записи голоса обычно стараются срезать все, что находится ниже 100 герц, но если срезать резко, то у меломанов может пойти из ушей кровь. Делают как правило плавный срез. Можно откуда-то стянуть код шумодава, но это достаточно сложное развлечение.

Так пользователь подобного софта я могу посоветовать ВСТАВИТЬ КОМПРЕССОР, так как порой собеседника просто НЕ СЛЫШНО, ну и конечно же включить его по-умолчанию. Параметры компрессора подбираются через пот и кровь, чтобы на выходе было по 0дб, при этом не было слышимых артефактов перегруза. Опять же, все зависит от целей - у аудиофилов от этого пойдет кровь ушами, а мне будет просто комфортнее, так как не придется напрягать слух.

Comment: Хорошо, я буду использовать предложенную вами функцию. Так понимаю, id всех устройств аудиозахвата упорядочены от 0 к последнему наибольшему. А что если какое то устройство отключается? Остальным, что были "за ним" по порядку id присваивается новый на единицу меньший?

Comment: Так же, есть ли функции для получения id последнего устройства? Т.е. просто количество устройств по сути. В NAudio во всяком случае такое есть.

Comment: Вы предложили частоты 44100 или 48000. А как узнать какую частоту устройство поддерживает нативно? Её и надо брать в любом случае?

Comment: Нет, мой софт не нацелен на хипстеров =) Я пишу программу удалённого доступа и мне нужен режим голосового чата. Ясно, что супер крутые навороты мне не нужны. Просто, хочу сделать не хуже, чем в TeamViewer. Ширину сэмпла я возьму 16 бит. А по поводу компресса, можно по-подробнее что это за штука такая.

Comment: Хотя вот по поводу частот и ширины сэмплов есть вот такое значение в структуре: `WAVEINCAPS.dwFormats` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743839(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: И вы в курсе, что `WAVEINCAPS.szPname` (Product name in a null-terminated string) имеет точное такое же ограничение по длине (видимо как раз эту функцию и использует NAudio).

Comment: Проверьте сами, или может я что-то не так делаю: https://pastebin.com/cXNFR7h4

Comment: Имена можно взять через Директ Саунд: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429143/get-the-full-audio-device-name-from-windows, компрессор - то, что динамически увеличивает громкость, чтобы оппонента всегда было слышно нормально, при переподключении воозможно все что угодно, даже генерация нового имени - делаем рескан, последнее устройство - это waveInGetNumDevs()-1

Comment: У меня выводит вместо имён кракозябры. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.dsenumcallback(v=vs.85).aspx. Я и локаль русскую сделал, и wcout использовал. Что там не так: https://pastebin.com/bNXzarmn?

Comment: Да и `DirectSoundEnumerate` использует перечисление по GUID, а не по индексам. Как различить? Взять с `waveInGetDevCaps` начало имени и искать его в списке после перечисление? Как-то не очень выглядит хорошо, если честно...

Comment: Ну если выводить через `wprintf`, то получается. Только `DirectSoundEnumerate` похоже перечисляет устройства аудиовоспроизведения. А мне нужны устройства аудиозахвата, и по индексам причём, с полным именем, количеством каналов и поддерживаемой частотой и шириной сэпла... Всё бы можно взять из getWaveInDevCaps, кроме полного имени!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693013/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0

Answer (score 2):

Я в своей программе делал так

```
private MMDeviceEnumerator _DeviceEnumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();

/// <summary>
/// Получение устройств воспроизведения
/// </summary>
private void GetAudioOutDevices()
{
    //var devices = _DeviceEnumerator
    //                    .EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Render, DeviceState.Active);

        //List<string> names = new List<string>();
        //foreach (var device in devices)
        //{
        //    names.Add(device.FriendlyName);
        //}
        ////список названий устройств воспроизведения
        //AudioOutDeviceNames = new List<string>(names);

        //устройство по-умолчанию
        AudioOutDefaultDevice = _DeviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia);
}
```

В закомментированном куске как раз формируется список устройств воспроизведения.

Устройство записи так

```
//выбор микрофона или устройства записи по-умолчанию
var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
CaptureDevices = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.Active).ToArray();
var defaultDevice = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Capture, Role.Console);
SelectedDevice = CaptureDevices.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == defaultDevice.ID);
```

Comment: У меня для дефолтного устройства ID равен `{0.0.0.00000000}.{4750ea41-98aa-4f98-9448-576b5d2ee2a4}`. Это типо 0?

Comment: Что-то слабо напоминает. Может где-то в этой строчке спрятано искомое значение?..

Comment: @D.Stark Какое искомое значение? `device.FriendlyName` - выдает в текстовом значении название устройства.

Comment: @D.Stark Метод `GetDefaultAudioEndpoint()` в зависимости от параметров выдает устройство записи или воспроизвдения по-умолчанию.

Comment: Мне нужен `Device Number` и `DeviceFriendlyName` вместе. Для каждого устройства.