# Динамическое улучшение качества записи голоса

Tags: c#, аудио, звукозапись, naudio

Каким образом можно улучшить качество записи голоса с микрофона динамически (т.к. звук будет передаваться на другой компьютер)?

Мне не требуются очень изощрённые и продвинутые решения.
Ограничиваемся установкой шумового порога и использованием аудио компрессора (усреднение громкости - громкие звуки занижаются, а тихие усиляются).

Так же меня не интересуют подробности реализации таковых алгоритмов. Мне нужны готовые решения. Например, с помощью NAudio я захватываю звук с микрофона. С помощью чего я могу установить шумовой порог и получить возможности компрессора?

Comment: Вообще можно придумать несколько подходов в зависимости от типа шумов и тд. Для простого сгодиться и эквалайзер - https://code.google.com/archive/p/practicesharp/downloads . С его помощью можно сглаживать частотный диапазон. Есть платные решения типа http://www.mitov.com/products/audiolab#overview . Эта штука уже много чего из коробки умеет. Можно заняться обучением нейросети и датамайнингом, но это уже слишком много человеко-часов

Comment: Я так понимаю этой штуке задаётся диапазон частот и всё что вне этого диапазона будет _мягко_ срезано?

Comment: Вот говоря о шумовом пороге (например, реализован в TeamViewer): что это вообще такое? Указывается нижняя граница частотного диапазона?

Comment: @emre Меня интересует только установка шумового порога (на сколько я сейчас понимаю, это нижняя граница частотного диапазона, и всё что ниже будет удалено). Не совсем догоняю что по ссылкам, но мне нужна **бесплатная библиотека**. Не важно что там в ней ещё есть, лишь бы поставленная задача выполнялась)

Comment: @emre А по поводу динамического компресса что скажете? Может он нафиг не нужен?

Comment: Шумовой порог это не граница частотного диапазона. Это именно порог по амплитуде (так работают примитивные шумоподавители без спектрального вычитания). Потом, про спектральное вычитание. К своему удивлению, я обнаружил, что вычитание белого шума на уровне этого самого шумового порога значительно увеличивает качество сигнала, с матаном этого дела все никак не разберусь. Компрессор, наверное, не повредит, но лучше многополосный (с кроссовером). Готовых инструментов для C# не знаю, все это делал сам на С, могу что-то подсказать, но, опять же, всего не знаю.

Comment: А какие значения может принимать шумовой порог? Можно ли организовать шумовой порог, компрессор и спектральное вычитание вместе при динамической записи, когда мы имеем один небольшой кусочек звуковых данных передаваемых в сеть?

Comment: Что вообще из себя представляет спектральное вычитание? Какой-то коэффициент вычисляется и вычитается? Как тут учитывается значение шумового порога, если "вычитание белого шума на уровне этого самого шумового порога "? За счёт чего работает компрессор? Имеется какое-то значение громкости - всё надо к этому значению подтянуть?

Comment: Похоже, что готовых решений реально нет. Нужно всё делать самому)

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Подскажите, если есть чем.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Дак поделитесь информацией или нет?!

Comment: Так, уже поделено же https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_enhancement

Comment: Но я не вижу здесь описания алгоритма. Как мне осуществить спектральное вычитание? Может поделитесь какими то сниппетами на С?.. Буду весьма благодарен)

Comment: "Сниппетами"?. Ну это сложноватая тема для сниппетов. Как посадить Space-X? Перейти из полета в падение, затормозиться, раскрыть крылышки, и сесть. Как сделать спектральное вычитание. Вычесть амплитуду спектра шума из амплитуды спектра сигнала. Возьмите какой-то из плагинов с открытым кодом, например, в приложении Audacity такое точно есть (сам недавно пользовался), и посмотрите, как там делается. Да и мои сниппеты на Ассемблере были бы, как там он с вашим Шарпом контачит.

Comment: "Вычесть амплитуду спектра шума из амплитуды спектра сигнала" - А откуда я могу знать эту амплитуду спектра шума? Хорошо, исходники Audacity посмотрю (спасибо за подсказку).

Comment: Вы ещё не подскажите, раз недавно смотрели, какой из модулей Audacity содержит этот код(ну там `include`, `locale`, `m4`)?

Comment: Я "недавно смотрел", делая несложную работку со звуком в Audacity, а вовсе не ковыряясь в его исходниках. Откуда копать визуально https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeKV9.png Плагины для него имеют тип/стандарт/название LADSPA. Их меньше, чем VST-шек, но тоже довольно много, там целые кучи открытого кода. Может, вам просто нужен правильный набор плагинов с БСД-лицензией, но как это все с C#...

Comment: libspeex то что вам нужно, там и шумоподавление, и AGC (автовыравнивание громкости), и то и другое на автопилоте неплохо работает, но не факт что оно для c# так просто заведется. *Если очень серьёзно настроены - читаем исходники mumble.*

Comment: Так это что (libspeex)? Библиотека?

Comment: Это какая то реализация кодека?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лично я бы не изобретал велосипед, а искал библиотеки для поддержки VST плагинов. И воспользовался бы уже готовыми VST с захардкодженными настройками.

В сторону чего я бы посмотрел (применять именно в такой последовательности):

- DeClip - убирает клиппинг звука (когда рот слишком близко к микрофону и микрофоная запись "клиппит")
- DeCkick/De-Crackle - убирает лишние щелчки. *(многие люди щелкают/клацают ртом во время разговора. Без этих звуков голос становится более ровным и приятным. Добавлять не обязательно.)*
- плагины типа 50Hz kicker -- убирают спектр частот которые полностью бесполезны для записи голоса (поиграйся, там от 50 до 100 нужно убирать).

  > Кстате, можно обойтись без 50Hz kicker плагина, а добавить его функционал
  > при помощи эквалайзера опустив в 0 весь спектр 0-50/80/100гц
- еквалайзер -- поднять басы (делает голос более глубоким) и высокие частоты после 10-15 кГц (делает голос более насыщенным и звонким и приятным за счет повышения громкости обертонов голоса [призвуки от голоса, которые окрашивают звук] ).
- Reverb - добавляет реверберацию. То есть эхо. Если поднастроить это дело и добавить совсем немного, то выходит практически всегда более приятный голос.
- Autotune - так же может улучшить звук голоса. Но может и ухудшить. В зависимости от того какие задачи ты перед собой ставить и как его настроишь.

> Последовательность применения VST плагинов играет роль. Имей это ввиду.

Практически все перечисленные плагины есть из коробки в любой DAW или скачиваются из трекеров или имеют бесплатные аналоги.

Сам таким не занимался, поэтому библиотек не подскажу. Вполне возможно что NAudio имеет поддержку VST.

---

PS1: И сначала поиграйся с этими плагинами напрямую из DAW, а потом уже применяй их настройки у себя в апликухе. Так же не забудь протестить это дело на разных микрофонах. Учитывай что твоя апликуха будет работать не с твоим конкретным микрофоном. И не только с твоим голосом. И то и другое может критически влиять на настройки.

PS2: Reaper имеет довольно неплохое количество бесплатных дней для использования. Окроме того он же не вырубается когда триал версия заканчивается, а продолжает тебя теребить что бы ты его купил. Так что у тебя может быть достаточно времени что бы наигратся плагинами и не нужно качать ничего пиратского.

PS3: De-noise в твоем случае использовать не советую. Хороший де-нойсер нужно обучать под конкретный микрофон/под конкретные настройки громкости микрофона/конкретное окружение в котором пользователь находится здесь и сейчас. То есть ни о какой универсальности и речи быть не может.

PS4: Так же имей ввиду что абсолютно универсального решения нет. Если бы было -- его бы всюду использовали и так :) Дай пользователям отключать каждую из "улучшалок" в настройках. У некоторых все равно какая-то улучшалка будет ухудшать звук. А у некоторых производительность важнее качества звука.

Comment: "_De-noise в твоем случае использовать не советую_" -- Почему не задействовать алгоритм спектрального вычитания?

Comment: @D.Stark "нужно обучать под конкретный микрофон/под конкретные настройки громкости микрофона.". То есть прийдется каждого пользователя просить "обучать" подавитель звука микрофона. А при изменении настрек микрофона проводить настройки подавителя шума заново. Или при переходе в другое окружение с ноутбуком. Это не будет в достаточной мере универсально. Но решение применять или не применять все равно на тебе.

Comment: Так же плохо обученный де-нойсер может порождать лишние артефакты звука ( "писки") которые будут резать в ухо не хуже самого шума... Или же обрезать спектр голоса что ухудшит само качество голоса, если микрофон сам по себе шумный... Короче, с де-нойсером все достаточно сложно и не факт что реально окупится его применение в случае с "универсальным" решением для разных микрофонов/пользователей/окружения при настройке в автоматическом режиме..

Comment: Что бы понять про что я говорю, попробуй настроить денойсер через плагин рипера ReaFir (substract mode) и потом применить эти же настройки на абсолютно другом микрофоне. А лучше -- на нескольких. Понятие того про что я говорю прийдет само собой. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOh04O6p6Vw