# NAudio 1.8 Запись и воспроизведение звука

Tags: c#, аудио, звукозапись, naudio

```
List<byte> data = new List<byte>();

WaveIn waveIn = new WaveIn();
waveIn.BufferMilliseconds = 10000;
waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(96000, 8, 2);
waveIn.DataAvailable += (s, e_) => data.AddRange(e_.Buffer);
waveIn.StartRecording();

Thread.Sleep(9000);
waveIn.StopRecording();

MessageBox.Show("Play: " + data.Count);

IWavePlayer waveOut = new WaveOut();
waveOut.Init(new RawSourceWaveStream(data.ToArray(), 0, data.Count, new WaveFormat(96000, 8, 2)));
waveOut.Play();
```

Каким образом я могу вести бесконечную запись? Вот устанавливаю (объясните ещё пожалуйста, зачем) `BufferMilliseconds` на значение времени записи. Если попробовать ставить `int.MaxValue` или -1, будет исключение. Как я могу вести запись бесконечно долго (например, для трансляции звука на другой компьютер)?

Так же, если кто владеет информацией о работе со звуком, прошу помочь мне разобраться в следующих подобных вопросах, с которыми может столкнуться любой при работе с NAudio:

[Получение полного имени устройства аудиозахвата](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/696725/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0)

[Динамическое улучшение качества записи голоса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693013/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0)

Comment: BufferMilliseconds это как раз время записи в e_.Buffer . И Я не совсем понимаю Ваш вопрос "как я могу вести запись бесконечно долго" , Просто не останавливайте запись и все.

Comment: Если я буду вести запись более 10 установленных секунд, то результирующие данные будут ужасно искажены в порядке своего следования. Запись обрывается, через некоторое время снова продолжается и т.д. Попробуйте сами)

Comment: Что делает `BufferMilliseconds` я и сам знаю - ограничение на запись (установил 10 с, значит _не более_ 10 с и должна вестись запись). Вопрос был почему без него ничего не работает?.. Вообще запись не ведётся. Никак. 0 байт!

Comment: А вот как я предложил в коде сейчас, всё работает корректно. Только есть маленькие неприятности типо пары щелчков при завершении воспроизведения, да и не все форматы записи поддерживает NAudio, как оказывается (например, попытка стерео записи на 96 кГц с 16 битным сэмплом вызовет исключение, хотя моё устройство такой формат поддерживает - проверял через `waveInGetDevCaps`).

Comment: Кстати, тот же формат записи, но с 8 битным сэмплом исключения не вызовет.

Comment: BufferMilliseconds это именно длина буфера, а не длина записи. Вам нужно полученные байты в e_.Buffer добавлять не в лист (ибо там сохранится ссылка, а не значение) а копировать именно значения.

Comment: Вот так: https://pastebin.com/vZBAn77R? Это не дало никакого эффекта. Запись проигрывается на 500 мс, а потом навсегда умолкает. Нули с конца я тоже удалял, но это в любом же случае не должно портить _всю_ запись?

Comment: Поставьте breakpoint на код внутри waveIn.DataAvailable , есть подозрение что оно не возникает из-за Thread.Sleep(..), потому и записи нет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62912/discussion-between-eblomyac-and-d-stark).

Comment: Я не правильно вам написал, что запись вовсе не ведётся и там 0 байт. Запись просто составляет 500 мс с последующей парой щелчков через 3-4 секунды. А так, там несколько десятков килобайт. Событие `DataAvailable` создаётся 3 раза, успешно обрабатывается, а массив пополняется сразу на несколько килобайт. В случае с рабочим кодом (это который я предлагал в вопросе), вызов события происходит вообще 1 раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решили в чате, мало ли кто столкнется:

Разделите начало и конец записи без использования: `Thread.Sleep(9000);` ибо блокируется обработка сообщений, в том числе и `WaveIn.DataAvailable(..)`
`BufferMilliseconds` можно оставить по умолчанию.